# Tomcat not running

Tags: eclipse, tomcat6, java

For some reasons tomcat does not run. I've looked at various tutorials and (as usual) the solutions won't work, I've put the log output below. I have done a fresh install of tomcat as well as linking it to eclipse however when trying to start the service in eclipse this is the output before the server stops.

```
    INFO: Server startup in 488 ms
    08-Apr-2013 09:42:23 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
    SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[8005]: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:406)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:676)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:628)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
    08-Apr-2013 09:42:23 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol pause
    INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
    08-Apr-2013 09:42:24 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
    INFO: Stopping service Catalina
     08-Apr-2013 09:42:24 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
    INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
```

Comment: you have another application listening in port 8005

Comment: It tells you that something is already running on port 8005.  Find that process, stop it and restart Tomcat.  What OS are you using?

Comment: Using windows 7 , K i'll stop that now

Comment: in task manager, check for any other java processes running

Comment: 've got this assignment due in a few days , thanks for the feedback it helped straight away !!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you find out which process is listening on a port on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

This exception tells you, that some other application is listening on the same port (`8005`).

The challenge for you is to find the other process that is using the port.
You don't specify what OS you use.

On Windows you could use `netstat`, under Linux you could give `nmap`a try to find the other process.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can happen on Windows when nobody don't use port. Namely, Windows TCP engine sometime keep time-wait port for a long time. Solution is wait to Windows release the port or restart.
On Linux the Issue can happen only if there is other process. It can be found with lsof